# jhipster error 400 BAD REQUEST with $resource save

Tags: http, post, resources, jhipster

I ve created a Jhipster application with `yo jhipster` and created an entity hikelist with `yo jhipster:entity hikelist`.

When I m trying to save my entity using the services et controllers generated by jhipster I m getting a BAD REQUEST 400. I can't find the reason of this error. The java resource is not called. Is there a way to get more information of the causes of this issue in my http request?

My backend resource :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/hikelists",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = "application/json")
@Timed
public void create(@RequestBody HikelistDTO hikelist) {
    log.debug("REST request to save Hikelist : {}", hikelist);
    hikelistRepository.save(hikelist);
}
```

The create function with http call on client side :

```
$scope.create = function () {
Hikelist.save($scope.hikelist,
  function () {
    $scope.hikelists = Hikelist.query();
    $('#saveHikelistModal').modal('hide');
    $scope.clear();
  });
};
```

Did I miss something? Is there anything else to configure?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm working through the same issue myself tonight... hopefully by tomorrow I'll have an answer for you.

Comment: I'm facing the very same error... @user2495290 did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your JSON is not serializing correctly into your DTO, more than likely because of an ID or some other value that you don't really want to touch by hand, but instead want your DB to manage. I just faced the same issue, and found a nice, clean workaround, without changing the Angular at all:

1. Add two new methods to your DTO so that it can be instantiated from a JSON string, or by null:

   ```
   public UserDTO(String firstName, String lastName, String email, Map<String, Boolean> roles) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.email = email;
       this.roles = roles;
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public static UserDTO fromJsonToUserDTO(String json) {
       return new JSONDeserializer<UserDTO>()
       .use(null, UserDTO.class).deserialize(json);
   }
   ```
2. Update your service to accept a JSON structure rather than a direct DTO, and then convert to DTO inline, using only the fields you wanted.

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/account",
           method = RequestMethod.POST,
           produces = "application/json")
   @Timed
   public void saveAccountFromJSON(@RequestBody String json) throws IOException {
       UserDTO userDTO = UserDTO.fromJsonToUserDTO(json);
       userService.updateUserInformation(userDTO.getFirstName(), userDTO.getLastName(), userDTO.getEmail());
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, well, just adding an empty constructor in my DTO object solved the problem.